# i am getting an error at oledbdatareader saying no given value for one or more required parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oledb, rdbms

I have a webpage called blogwebsite and in that I have a textbox and search button. I am passing the value of textbox on button click to another webform called blogseacrh through session. I also have a database bound through these webforms. In this blogsearch webpage I have taken the session variable in a textbox. Using this textbox value I am writing a oledbcommand select query. I am fetching data from the database using this textbox value and want to display it on the blogsearch webpage. For this to happen I am using oledbdatareader to read the data and then write the fetched data in the textbox. But when I am running the webpage when I click on search button it gives me the error at the oledbdatareader line saying that no given value given for one or more required parameters.

I really can't understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone please give me a solution?

This is the button click event which is working perfectly

```
protected void btn_srch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["name"] = txt_bnm.Text;
    Response.Redirect("blogseacrh.aspx");
}
```

This is the code that needs to be executed on another webpage on button click event

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (Session["name"] != null)
        {
            con.Open();

            txt2_bnm.Text = Session["name"].ToString();

           cmd = new OleDbCommand("select user  from tbl_blogs where book_name='" + txt2_bnm.text + "',con); `                                


            OleDbDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (d.Read())
            {
                user = d["user"].ToString();
                Response.Write(user);
            }
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select blogs from tbl_blogs where book_name='" +  txt2_bnm.Text + "' ", con);    

            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                blogs = dr["blogs"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect(blogs);
            }
            con.Close();
}
```

I have also checked all the field names and table name and they are all correct as well.

Can someone please solve this error. i have an assignment to complete please.

Comment: Your code sample doesn’t look right: `select user  from tbl_blogs where book_name='" + enter `

Comment: where and how is the value of "enter" being set? You don't show that part.

Comment: @stuartd- Sorry ,the rest of part had gotten erased. I have writtern it again.

Comment: As you may be able to tell from the highlighting, you have some syntax errors in your code. The most glaring is the lack of an ending quote on your first OleDbCommand. Even with that fixed, you leave yourself open to SQL Injection attacks; One can enter some rather simple commands into `txt2_bnm` and delete all data from your database.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i have added the quotes in my real code in vs code but here the quotes have gone missing.The code is running properly until i click on the search button and the error at oledbdatareader occurs.